# How to set maps (apart from albedo, normal and metallic) at runtime in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I'm trying to dynamically set textures for my game object.
It works like this:

```
        var skin = _skinTable[index] as Hashtable;
        var renderer = CurrentShip.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>();

        renderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", skin["albedo"] as Texture);
        renderer.material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", skin["normal"] as Texture);
        renderer.material.SetTexture("_MetallicGlossMap", skin["metallic"] as Texture);
```

Where can I find names (first argument of SetTexture) for other maps, like Height, Occlusion etc? 
(I'm talking about Standard Shader)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the available map channels if you select your shader in the inspector

[image]

For a full standard shader you can check the source
https://github.com/TwoTailsGames/Unity-Built-in-Shaders/blob/master/DefaultResourcesExtra/Standard.shader